# PHP imagecreatefrom gif() not working for animated gif

Tags: php

I'm letting users upload image files from their desktop and then using the PHP image routines to create thumbnails and resize images for the user's directory.  But this doesn't seem to work at all for an animated gif.  imagecreatefromgif(), for example, seems to peel off the first image of the animation and only work with it. Do I need to completely bypass these functions to get the complete uploaded animated gif to the user's directory?

Thanks

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) - *"When reading animated GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer."*

Comment: The gdlib image library does not deal with animations. Everything is considered to be one static image.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351795/keep-gif-animation for some hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot resize an animated gif image in the way you easily do with jpeg, bmp or other image formats. The function imagecreatefromgif() is not going to help you by any means, so take a look at the below link.

http://phpimageworkshop.com/tutorial/5/manage-animated-gif-with-imageworkshop.html

It should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

To upload animated gif images I use this script:

```
$fileinfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." .   $fileinfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../avatar/" . $newFilename);
$location="avatar/" . $newFilename;
```

It is simple and may not be a very functional one, but with animated gifs I have no problems.

Comment: Read the question clearly, before answering. He want he resize the give without loosing the animation, not just upload image.